# Loading files in a folder using php

Tags: php, file-listing

I tried loading the names of the files in the Books directory, with the following code:

```
<?php

  if ($handle = opendir('/Books')) {
    echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
    echo "Entries:\n";

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
      echo "$entry\n";
    }
 closedir($handle);
 }
?>
```

But it seems not to display the names. Am I doing this wrong or not locating the right directory?

Comment: Try using the full path not the relative path.  Like "/var/www/vhosts/domaain.com/httpdocs/Books"

Comment: @karmafunk you mean the inverse I hope?

Comment: The above works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems as if you're using the wrong directory... I think the `Books` folder is in the same directory as your script?

Then use only `opendir('Books')` which is a ***relative*** path to the directory.

When you use `/Books` you use the `Books` folder located in the root directory of your filesystem. (this is called an ***absolute*** path)

Comment: I changed it to your suggestion, but it still doesn't display the list.

Comment: Try to enable your errors with `error_reporting(-1); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` and say me which error the `opendir()` call throws?

Comment: I used chrome debugger function and it shows that the php code has been put in comments. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: I found my problem. I needed to save it as a .php and not html

Comment: Oh lol... But my answer has helped you too?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would use `scandir()` for this one:

```
<?php  
$scanner = scandir("theFolder");  
foreach ($scanner as $fileName) {  
    echo "$fileName<br>";  
}  
?>
```

Comment: This isn't explaining the error of the asker.

Comment: If you just want files not sub directories look for all the `$fileName` variables with dots.

Comment: And executable files with no extension aren't listed? Then you have to check for `!is_dir("$folder/$fileName")`